# To-do's after installing Scientific-Linux 6.1 for Desktop purposes

Tags: scientific-linux

How can I install fresh versions of these apps on Scientific-Linux 6.1/64bit?:

- VLC player (it's not in the default repositories and all I can find is an outdated VLC in rpmforge)
- Chromium/Google Chrome
- Flash Player
- VirtualBox
- A Microsoft Paint alternative

Answer (score 1):

Scientific Linux uses the `yum` package manager. I don't use it (`pacman` is what Arch Linux runs), but the command should be similar to this (use bash-completion if it isn't):

```
sudo yum install vlc
```

Chrome can be downloaded from Google, but Chromium should be in the repository:

```
sudo yum install chromium
```

For a paint alternative, I suggest GIMP. It's more like Photoshop, but it can function like paint:

```
sudo yum install gimp
```

Virtualbox should be the same way:

```
sudo yum install virtualbox
```

Do note, though, that Scientific Linux might not come with any repositories enabled. Google is your friend, though: http://scientificlinuxforum.org/index.php?showtopic=229

Comment: i know i can install it with yum.. just wanted to ask that which repositories do i have to use for scientific-linux? fedora's repos?

Comment: kolourpaint is good as an ms paint alternative, not GIMP..

Comment: i just don't want KDE when I'm using GNOME

Comment: GIMP is really the only thing I can suggest. Also, you can run KDE and GNOME applications side-by-side. You won't need to use the KDE desktop, just a few of the libraries required by the binaries.

Comment: +there is a problem using ex.: fedora repos... fedora doesn't have 6 years support for a given version of the main os...

Comment: Well, that's the tradeoff. Either long term support, or recent software.